# Clusters labels in dendrogram

Tags: r, dendrogram

I'm wondering - is there any way how to add labels of clusters into dendrogram. See simple example:

```
hc = hclust(dist(mtcars))
plot(hc, hang = -1)
rect.hclust(hc, k = 3, border = "red")
```

[image]

Desired output should look like this:

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the coordinates of the place to put your clusters' labels:

**First axis:**
As you are calling `rect.hclust`, you might as well assign the result so you can use it to find the beginning of clusters (the first one begins at 1 the 2nd at 1 + the length of the first, etc.

```
rh <- rect.hclust(hc, k = 3, border = "red")
beg_clus <- head(cumsum(c(1, lengths(rh))), -1)
```

**Second axis:**
You just want to be above the red rectangle, which is at the middle of the height where you have k-1 clusters and the height where you have k clusters. Let's say you're aiming at 4/5 of the distance instead of 1/2:

```
y_clus <- weighted.mean(rev(hc$height)[2:3], c(4, 1))
```

**Putting the labels:**

```
text(x=beg_clus, y=y_clus, col="red", labels=LETTERS[1:3], font=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to adding text labels is in the `mjcgraphics` package that deals with cluster labels. See https://github.com/drmjc/mjcgraphics and https://rdrr.io/github/drmjc/mjcgraphics/man/rect.hclust.labels.html

```
rect.hclust.labels(hc, k=3, border = 1 ) # adds labels to clusters
```